# How to convert exponential form into decimal form in python

Tags: python

```
Output :-
8.881784197e-16
```

I want the same output in decimal form

Tried

```
def sqrt(value):
    num = 1
    while (value):
        num = num * 2
        value = value -1
    return num

num =  1 / float (square)
print float(num)
```

Note: square value changing from 1 to 100 so expected output is to get the answer in full decimal form but it's coming in exponential form

Answer (score 1):

To display all the digits you can try formatting:

```
print "%.25f" % a
# -0.0000000000000008881784197
```

where `25` is the number of digits after the point. You can change it.

Comment: I don't want extra zero's at end.

Comment: @user3464566 That's why you can change the number `25`.

Comment: I want the same for 200 numbers. I  can't go every time and change that floating reference. Is there any way to print accurate value after decimal not in exponential form?